# at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdiplusStartup(IntPtr& token, StartupInput& input, StartupOutput& output)\n

Tags: excel, aws, net, .net-6.0, epplus

Estoy desarrollando en .NET 6 y cuando construyo con formato y colores el excel tengo el siguiente mensaje al desplegar en AWS

The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception. | System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libgdiplus' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibgdiplus: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n   at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdiplusStartup(IntPtr& token, StartupInput& input, StartupOutput& output)\n   at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip..cctor() | -2146233036